# How would I show that a set is not dense?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Consider the Cantor set. I want to prove that it is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Now it makes sense to me since the Cantor set misses entire open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. So my idea was to choose some open interval in the cantor set and show their is no element of the cantor set between the open interval. Not sure how to prove that though.

Comment: To show that $A$ is *not* dense in $X$, choose some $x\in X-A$ and find an open set $U$ containing $x$ and not intersecting $A$.

Answer (score 4):

The cantor set, $\mathcal{C}$, on say $[0, 1]$ is a closed set.  Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ was dense in $[0, 1]$, then $\overline{\mathcal{C}} = [0,1]$.  But $\overline{\mathcal{C}} = \mathcal{C}$.  A contradiction since $\mathcal{C} \neq [0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pedro.  I never claimed my proof was the most elegant way of seeing things.

Comment: The idea is the way to go, the way it is phrased is strange.

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor set is closed. A closed set is dense in the space iff it is the whole space.

In fact, the Cantor set is nowhere dense,  since $C^{\circ}=\varnothing$ and $\bar C=C$, we have $(\bar C)^\circ =\varnothing$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I just dont know how to prove it ;)

Comment: @user128349 Don't you know the Cantor Set is closed? It is an intersection of closed sets, namely, finite unions of closed intervals.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Actually everyone's comments makes sense to me. I am just trying to write out the proof nicely because details are important in mathematics even if its a short proof ;)

Comment: I guess I should have been more detailed and said that I want to show the cantor set is no where dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user128349 Not being dense and being nowhere dense are very different things.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 1):

> *So my idea was to choose some open interval in the cantor set and show their is no element of the cantor set between the open interval.*

Something went a bit haywire here. If you were to choose an "interval in the Cantor set" then that interval (being "in" the Cantor set) would obviously contain points of the Cantor set. Carefully review what "dense" means. If you know what "dense" means, then you'll see it isn't even dense in $[0,1]$.

$(\frac12,\frac{12}{20})$ is a nonempty open set that does not intersect the Cantor set.

Of course, there are many other choices for such an interval.